# ActionScript 3 (AS3) how to pick random array?

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3, flash, random

I have a problem, I don't know how to pick a random array .

```
var enemies:Array;

public function Main() {
enTimer = new Timer(1000);
enTimer.addEventListener("timer", createEnemy);
enTimer.start();
}

private function Enemy1():void {
var enemy1 = new Enemy1();
enemies.push(enemy1);
}

private function Enemy2():void {
var enemy2 = new Enemy2();
enemies.push(enemy2);
}

public function createEnemy():void {
//here is the problem how to pick up a random enemy ??
var EN = enemies[math.round(Math.random() * 2)];

stage.addChild(EN)
}
```

after this im geting an error:

> Implicit coercion of a value of type Array to an unrelated type
>   flash.display:DisplayObject.

Answer (score 4):

You've got a few problems with your code.

For starters, you're defining two functions, `Enemy1` and `Enemy2` but you also have what looks like two classes named `Enemy1` and `Enemy2`.  I would refrain from calling functions and classes the same name as it can get confusing.

In addition, the reason you are getting the error:

> Implicit coercion of a value of type Array to an unrelated type flash.display:DisplayObject.

Is because your `Enemy1` or `Enemy2` classes do not extend a `DisplayObject` class and only objects that are of the type `DisplayObject` can be added to the stage.  What object does your `Enemy1` and `Enemy2` classes inherit from?

Your enemy object class should look something like this as far as inheritance goes to ensure they become a `DisplayObject` type:

```
package {
    import flash.display.MovieClip;

    public class Enemy1 extends MovieClip {

        public function Enemy1() {

        }
    }
}
```

*or*

```
package {
    import flash.display.Sprite;

    public class Enemy1 extends Sprite {

        public function Enemy1() {

        }
    }
}
```

`MovieClip` and `Sprite` are two examples of objects that are part of the `DisplayObject` family of classes.